# Zalenium videos stored locally?

Tags: zalenium

In zalenium, As the Videos are displayed in Dashboard, my question is: are these videos stored in Zalenium docker image that we pulled ? or they are stored in local system? If they are stored in local system then how can we access them through file structure/ windows explorer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Videos are end up being stored inside the Zalenium container, more specifically in the `/home/seluser/videos` directory. Therefore, if you start Zalenium by mapping a local directory to the videos one inside the container, the videos will end up in your local directory.
Example in Windows (from the Zalenium docs):

```
    docker run --rm -ti --name zalenium -p 4444:4444 ^
      -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ^
      -v /c/Users/your_user_name/temp/videos:/home/seluser/videos ^
      --privileged dosel/zalenium start
```

`-v /c/Users/your_user_name/temp/videos:/home/seluser/videos` will map the local directory `/c/Users/your_user_name/temp/videos` in Windows to the `/home/seluser/videos` inside the container. So the videos will also be stored there.